# If item is not inside list, f.write(",") checks too many times

Tags: python

I'm not sure if my problems lies in the for loops or in the if statements.

I have a bunch of virtual routers inside of my home lab, where I with paramiko is able to fetch some ip route tables into ordinary text documents. With regex and split, I extract the exact data I want. The goal is to put this data into a .csv "scheme" so to speak, so that i can upload it to my website and do a live presentation of the network to my teacher (for the extra points!)

This is my current code. the problem lies within the seven last lines of code.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.5

### imports ###

import re
import sys
import csv

### Custom Functions ####


### VARIABLES ###

vrfarg = sys.argv[1]

bdiarray = []

### RUNTIME ####
c = open('output.csv', "w")
f = open('mplslist.txt', 'r')
for line in f:
    d = open(line, 'r')
    dsorted = sorted(d.readlines(), key=lambda x: int(x.split("BDI")[-1]))
    print(dsorted)
    for items in dsorted:
        bdi = re.findall(r'(?<=\BDI).*',items)
        print(bdi)
        for items in bdi:
            if items not in bdiarray:
                bdiarray.extend(bdi)
    d.close()
f.close()
print(bdiarray)

c.write(vrfarg + "\n")
c.write("VLANS:,")
for items in bdiarray:
    c.write(items + ",")
c.write("\n")

f = open('mplslist.txt', 'r')
for line in f:
    c.write(line.rstrip() + ",")
    d = open(line, 'r')
    dsorted = sorted(d.readlines(), key=lambda x: int(x.split("BDI")[-1]))
    print(dsorted)
    for d in dsorted:
        for items in bdiarray:
            if "BDI" + items in d:
                c.write("route ok!,")
            if not "BDI" + items in d:
                c.write(",")
```

For every line inside the route file, i want to check if "BDI"+somenumber is equal to items inside bdi array, So that every line inside the route file, runs through all the items inside bdiarray, if they names match, (if the lines contains the exact word) c.write("route ok!,") and for all of the items it does not match, it should do a c.write(",") (blank cell inside a CSV file)

The the output should be:

```
ROUTES TO ROUTER1,
VLANS:,9,708,3001,
ROUTER2,route ok!,route ok!,route ok!,
```

But the output is:

```
ROUTES TO ROUTER1,
VLANS:,9,708,3001,
ROUTER2,route ok!,,,,route ok!,,,,route ok!,
```

any suggestions?

I'm fully aware this is rather rubbish code, that i run through the file twice and such, I simply need a PoC to show my teacher, so he'll accept it as a exam topic (Networking and programming), optimizing comes later.

Comment: or this line run many times : `if not "BDI" + items in d:
                c.write(",")`

Comment: How come? It only prints whatever line f is at that moment i think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the two for-loops in the wrong order:

```
for items in bdiarray:
    ok = False
    for d in dsorted:
        if "BDI" + items in d:
            ok = True
            break
    c.write("route ok!," if ok else ",")
```

or with `any`:

```
for items in bdiarray:
    ok = any("BDI" + items in d for d in dsorted)
    c.write("route ok!," if ok else ",")
```

Comment: Thanks, It fixed it! Is there any way to get the string inside of the last d variable so that i can print it later in the script?

Comment: @BIGFATTOBY: inside what? Don't understand your question.

Comment: ok = any("BDI" + items in d for d in dsorted), the last "d" will be a variable for whatever item or line it is currently looking at, when it find the match i want to print the line it matched on. If it makes sense

Comment: if you need `d`, you have to go with my first version.

Comment: edit: your first example didn't work because im a rookie, thanks for help mate, it works like a charm

Answer (score 0):

I think if you remove these lines , your expected output will appear :

```
if not "BDI" + items in d:
    c.write(",")
```

Comment: look , when you are using these lines of code :


`for d in dsorted:`


`        for items in bdiarray:`


`            if "BDI" + items in d:`


`                c.write("route ok!,")`


the first condition is  ` if "BDI" + items in d:` your second `if` means otherwise

Comment: This only works if no output is needed when there's no match for a given `d` value. If nothing in `bdiarray` matches with `d`, this code won't produce an empty cell in the CSV file.

Comment: @Blckknght yeah , you are right , but this guy needs something like his expected output , you are saying right at all

Comment: @BIGFATTOBY what did you exactly need ? you need empty cell for routher that does not have route ?

Comment: @BIGFATTOBY replace this instead of your second if : `if not "BDI" + items in d:` `c.write("route not ok !,")` , then your csv file should be ok

Comment: Is there any difference from my last if statement and the line you just gave me?

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue has to do with how you're checking if the number you've found in your file is in your list. Your current code checks each item with each member of the list and writes some output for every check. That's not what you want. You only want one output to be written if a match is found, not one per item of the list.

Try replacing this loop:

```
for items in bdiarray:
    if "BDI" + items in d:
        c.write("route ok!,")
    if not "BDI" + items in d:
        c.write(",")
```

With this alternative (using `any` and a generator expression):

```
if any("BDI" + items in d for items in bdiarray):
    c.write("route ok!,")
else:
    c.write(",")
```

Comment: Fixed the problem with the extra commas thanks! Sadly it does not produce the extra comma representing an empty cell for router that does not have the route